# How do I show 2 rows per element using jsPDF Autotable hooks

Tags: typescript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

In TypeScript, I need to create a PDF with a table in which each element spans 2 rows instead of one, such as this table here:
[example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbKTE.png)

I am trying to do this using jsPDF Autotable, without using an HTML table as a template, and using columns (`head: "xxx", dataKey: "yyy"`) instead of body.

The Autotable library has apparently recently switched from using 'drawRow' and 'drawCell' to using Hooks such as 'willDrawCell', and I have been unable to find material on how to use these Hooks other than the documentation and basic example on the official repository's ReadMe (https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable).

I've attempted to adapt [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Paithankar/qhc1kdyd/22/) code using the old version of Autotable without much luck

```
 doc.autoTable(getColumns(), data, {
        theme: 'grid',
        startY: 60,
        drawRow: function (row, data) {
            // Colspan
            doc.setFontStyle('bold');
            doc.setFontSize(10);
            if (row.index === 0) {
                doc.setTextColor(200, 0, 0);
                doc.rect(data.settings.margin.left, row.y, data.table.width, 20, 'S');
                doc.autoTableText("Priority Group", data.settings.margin.left + data.table.width / 2, row.y + row.height / 2, {
                    halign: 'center',
                    valign: 'middle'
                });
                data.cursor.y += 20;
            }
             .....
            };
```

and since Hooks seem to work quite a bit differently my efforts have quickly devolved to blind trial and error brute force that is going nowhere.

Any practical examples of using jsPDF Autotable's Hooks, even if unrelated to my particular need, would be greatly appreciated and a great guide.